# Cleaning scraped <a href> rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, gsub, code-cleanup

I have scraped data from a website and entered it into an array using the code below:

```
  def process_course_details(course_details)
        details_array =[]
        details_link = true 
        entry_link = true

                details_info = {}
                # Sets all data in hash
                details_info[:url] = clean_link(course_details.search('div.coursedetails_programmeurl a'))
                details_array.push(details_info)
                print_details_info(details_info)


             entry_link = course_details.search('ul.details_tabs').first

     end
```

The code above stores the element being pulled as such:

```
<a href="http://www.abdn.ac.uk/study/courses/undergraduate/C8R1/">View course details on provider's website</a>
```

But I'd like to clean the above to the below:

```
http://www.abdn.ac.uk/study/courses/undergraduate/C8R1/
```

or failing that remove the apostrophe and have this:

```
<a href="http://www.abdn.ac.uk/study/courses/undergraduate/C8R1/">View course details on providers website</a>`
```

Comment: _"I'm trying to store this in an sqlite3 database but as the text has an apostrophe I can't do this"_ – I'm pretty sure that SQLite can store apostrophes. How does your code to store the text look like?

Comment: any gem you are using for scrapping?

Comment: When storing other data I've scraped into the database the apostrophe provided errors and stopped it. Once I had cleaned the apostrophe and it no longer was part of the array the code worked and the table was created.

                db = SQLite3::Database.open('ahhh.sqlite3')

                db.execute "INSERT INTO aahah (uname, cname, duration, qualification, url, entry) VALUES ('#{@uni_name}', #{@course_name}', '#{@course_duration}', '#{@course_qual}', '#{@details_entry}', '#{@requirements}')"
            
if you're talking about the array I can post that

Comment: I'm using mechanize for scraping, which requires/uses nokogiri too.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the href with Nokogiri like this:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML('<a href="http://www.abdn.ac.uk/study/courses/undergraduate/C8R1/">View course details on provider\'s website</a>')
html.xpath("//a/@href").to_s # => "http://www.abdn.ac.uk/study/courses/undergraduate/C8R1/"
```

Comment: I'm extracting several (probably a couple thousand) of these a hrefs, so I'm not quite sure how I would implement what you've suggested on a grander scale than the example you've provided.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention this in question and so no one knows how do you keep those couple of thousand hrefs. If it's an array, just make a loop.

Comment: There is a lot of code and the question would be too long if I included it all. All I want to do is create a gsub method which would be able to clean the a href as its stored (shown in the question) within the array. If you have the time to help and need more information I could email you the code in more depth. I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: I don't see arrays anywhere in the question. Your method accepts `text`, there is no such class in ruby. You say you get undefined method gsub!, you can't get this error for string, that means you are not passing a string but something else, but you cut the error message on the most important part. Please edit your question with an example of existing structure of your variables, what do you want to pass and how do you want to transform. What I currently see in the question is "_html_ I want to clean this to _link_"

Comment: I've updated the question to include the segment in which the array is created

Comment: sqlite escapes apostrophes with double apostrophes. try `your_string.gsub!(/\'/,"''")`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990596/cleaning-scraped-a-href-rails#comment63425060_37990596):

> When storing other data I've scraped into the database the apostrophe
>   provided errors and stopped it. Once I had cleaned the apostrophe and
>   it no longer was part of the array the code worked and the table was
>   created.
>
> ```
> db = SQLite3::Database.open('ahhh.sqlite3')
> db.execute "INSERT INTO aahah (uname, cname, duration, qualification, url, entry) VALUES ('#{@uni_name}', #{@course_name}', '#{@course_duration}', '#{@course_qual}', '#{@details_entry}', '#{@requirements}')"
> ```

You are inserting the values via string interpolation:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (foo, bar) VALUES ('#{@foo}', '#{@bar}')")
```

Apparently, if the interpolated strings contain an apostrophe, your SQL string likely becomes invalid. Even worse, this code is prone to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Instead you should use parameter markers and let the SQLite gem handle the escaping:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (foo, bar) VALUES (?, ?)", [@foo, @bar])
```

This allows you to safely insert apostrophe and other special characters.

Comment: I ran your suggestion and it returned this error: **bind_param': can't prepare Nokogiri::XML::Element (RuntimeError)**

Comment: @Akamaru my suggestion doesn't contain any Nokogiri related code.